# Add custom Wepart to Enterprise wiki Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I am  trying to recreate the NoteBoard webpart for office 365. The NoteBoard web part is disabled by the Microsoft in Office 365 as they are trying to promote Yammer.

Can someone point me how to create a custom web part or app part and attach it a Publishing layout page. As the Enterprise wiki page is just a Publishing page.

1. I was planning to create a web/ app part
2. Activate the feature in the site collections
3. Add the Web part to Enterprise Wiki layout page